# For loop is not looping in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am currently trying to parse the contents of cells using VBA. Here is my code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim integ As Integer
Dim counter As Range
Dim counts As Integer
Dim num As Integer
num = 2
counts = 0
Dim element As Variant
Dim count As Integer
Dim players(1 To 100) As String
Dim lineup As String
Dim salary As Integer
For Each counter In Range("F2:F11")
    starter_letter = "L"
    lineup = counter.Value
    Dim arr() As String
    arr() = Split(lineup)
    For Each element In arr
        If element = "PG" Or element = "SG" Or element = "SF" Or element = "PF" Or element = "C" Or element = "G" Or element = "F" Or element = "UTIL" Then
            counts = counts + 1
        Else
            players(counts) = players(counts) + element + " "
        End If
    Next element
    For count = 1 To 8
        letter = Chr(Asc(starter_letter) + count)
        Range(letter + CStr(num)).Value = Trim(players(count))
    Next count
    num = num + 1
Next counter
End Sub
```

I will include pictures to illustrate the problem.

I am trying to take the names out of each cell and assign them to different cells.

It works for the first cell I parse, but the counter doesn't proceed to the next cell. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Here are the contents of each cell as requested:

```
SF Ben Simmons C Marc Gasol PG CJ McCollum F Nicolas Batum PF Enes Kanter G Terry Rozier SG Andrew Harrison UTIL Wayne Selden Jr.
PG Kemba Walker C Marc Gasol G CJ McCollum UTIL Nicolas Batum F Enes Kanter SG Terry Rozier SF Al-Farouq Aminu PF Channing Frye
PG Kemba Walker C Kristaps Porzingis UTIL CJ McCollum SF Nicolas Batum G Terry Rozier F Josh Jackson PF Dirk Nowitzki SG Dwyane Wade
F LeBron James C Marc Gasol UTIL CJ McCollum SF Jaylen Brown SG Terry Rozier G Josh Jackson PG Wayne Selden Jr. PF Marreese Speights
C Dwight Howard PG Kemba Walker SG CJ McCollum PF Enes Kanter F Bobby Portis G Terry Rozier UTIL Wayne Selden Jr. SF Jae Crowder
SF LeBron James PF Al Horford G CJ McCollum C Myles Turner SG Denzel Valentine PG Terry Rozier UTIL Wayne Selden Jr. F Marreese Speights
C Dwight Howard SG CJ McCollum G Elfrid Payton SF Nicolas Batum PF Enes Kanter F Wesley Matthews PG Terry Rozier UTIL Channing Frye
PG Kemba Walker G CJ McCollum UTIL Dennis Smith Jr. SF Brandon Ingram F Enes Kanter C Bobby Portis SG Terry Rozier PF Jarrett Allen
G Kemba Walker F Al Horford UTIL CJ McCollum SG Jordan Clarkson SF Nicolas Batum PG Terry Rozier PF Dirk Nowitzki C Jahlil Okafor
SF LeBron James C Joel Embiid SG Nicolas Batum UTIL Bobby Portis G Terry Rozier PG Wayne Selden Jr. F Jarrett Allen PF Marreese Speights
```

These are the cells that need parsed.

[image: These are the cells that need parsed.]

These are the output of the current VBA code.

[image: These are the output of the current VBA code.]

Comment: You have 3 For Loops. Which one is not looping?

Comment: First the concatenate character is `&` in vba not `+` so change `Range("F" + CStr(counter))` to `Range("F" & counter)`

Comment: The outer most one "counter" since it is only parsing cell F2 over and over instead proceeding onto F3, F4, etc.

Comment: Second, Always, always declare the parent of any range object `Worksheets("contest-standings-53189415".Range("F" & counter)`

Comment: The & suggestion did not solve the issue and I have used + before and it works the same.

Comment: Your counter goes up to 11, not more

Comment: Right but that isn't the issue. The issue is that it is not getting past 2.

Comment: & and + only work the same when it's text. If any of the values just happen to be numbers, VBA will add them together, not concatenate them.

Comment: Thanks. I ensured they were all text.

Comment: Third:  Learn about `Cells()` it will eliminate the need to convert number to strings when trying to set a column.  just to have excel convert them back to numbers.  It is like converting DC power to AC just to convert it back to DC to power your phone.

Comment: Will that solve the looping issue?

Comment: These are all suggestions to speed up your code.

Comment: You are doing a lot of unnecessary conversions and as such, it slows down the code, and makes it harder to follow and debug.

Comment: You assign a value to "Counts" before defining it in memory, so that's another mistake worth fixing. What happens if you `dim counter as integer` before your for-loop?

Comment: The code runs basically instantaneously since I only need to run it for cells F2:F11 anyway. I just don't know why it isn't looping.

Comment: You need to step through your code step by step and watch the values.  It will help you figure out why.

Comment: In this line `Range(letter + CStr(counter)).Value = Trim(players(count))` count always runs from 1 to 8 but players is populated abvoe in `players(counts)` and counts presumably goes beyond 8.

Comment: If I need make players an array from 1 to 8, I get a out of range error when running the code.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question of why this is happening, but a workaround would be to loop over the cells instead. So `dim counter as range` and then do `For each counter in Range("F2:F11")`. That way your assignment of the `lineup` variable would be easier too: `lineup = counter.value`

Comment: I just implemented that solution and unfortunately I am still getting the same result.

Comment: "need make players an array from 1 to 8" - clearly that is not going to work, but then it's not what I suggested.

Comment: Not sure we can do much more without some debugging information. Try stepping through the algorithm and examining your variables at each step, and see if you can pinpoint where something isn't being updated.

Comment: (Or at the very least, your updated code)

Comment: The code is updated with neophlegm's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim inpts As Variant
Dim players() As Variant

With Worksheets("sheet3")
    inpts = .Range("F2:F11").Value
    ReDim players(1 To UBound(inpts, 1), 1 To 10)
    Dim counts As Long
    counts = 0
    For counter = LBound(inpts) To UBound(inpts)
        Dim arr() As String
        arr = Split(inpts(counter, 1))
        Dim element
        For Each element In arr
            If element = "PG" Or element = "SG" Or element = "SF" Or element = "PF" Or element = "C" Or element = "G" Or element = "F" Or element = "UTIL" Then
                counts = counts + 1
            Else
                players(counter, counts) = players(counter, counts) & element & " "
            End If
        Next element
        counts = 0
    Next counter
    .Range("L2").Resize(UBound(players, 1), UBound(players, 2)).Value = players
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This line players(counter, counts) = players(counter, counts) & element & " " gave me an out of range error

Comment: 0. It is on the first iteration

Comment: What is the value of `elements`?

Comment: "SF" is the value of elements

Comment: The update didn't run at all since the for loop uses "element" but the next control uses "elements"

Comment: I changed elements to element and got the same out of range error.

Comment: Again, what are the values when it errors?  You can't just say it errors.  we need the values of the variable when it errors.

Comment: At least give us the values of  those cells in text form so we can copy paste and test.

Comment: Counts is 11, counter is 2, and element is CJ

Comment: Okay what is the max number of players a row can have?  Change the `1 to 10` to the max number possible.

Comment: There are only 8 players in every row.

Comment: SF Ben Simmons C Marc Gasol PG CJ McCollum F Nicolas Batum PF Enes Kanter G Terry Rozier SG Andrew Harrison UTIL Wayne Selden Jr.

Comment: PG Kemba Walker C Marc Gasol G CJ McCollum UTIL Nicolas Batum F Enes Kanter SG Terry Rozier SF Al-Farouq Aminu PF Channing Frye

Comment: Those are the text contents of the cells F2 and F3

Comment: put the values of the F2:F11 as text in your original post so I can copy paste.

Comment: Just added to the original post

Comment: I forgot to reset `counts` to 0 after the inner loop.  see edit.  it is tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am very grateful for your help!